# Chrome Extension: Show Images Only (No Text) on Page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to write a Chrome extension that shows images ONLY on a page (hides all text), when the plugin is enabled?

There are plugins available that hide all images. I need the opposite: a page with just the images, and all text hidden.

Ideally, this behavior should also be restricted to some location on the page (e.g., inside a particular DIV), but that's not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide all html tags but `img` then, yes, it's possible and is very easy to do. You can do this using a [content style](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that overwrites the CSS of the target page and hide everything except images tags.

Here is how you can do it:

`manifest.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Test extension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Some description",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon-16.png",
        "128": "images/icon-128.png"
    },
    "default_locale": "en",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "css" : [
                "styles/contentstyle.css"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

`scripts/contentstyle.css`

```
body {
    visibility: hidden;
}

* img {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Note that this CRX won't show images set as a `background-image` through CSS, only the `img` tags.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Just one more thing: When I click the Extension again, I want to toggle that mode off. Right now, the Image-Only mode gets activated when the plugin is clicked, but there's no easy way to go back. Just a "nice-to-have", but if too complicated it's OK.